# codeigniter route problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

result I want :

```
greeting/102/steve =>  greeting/index/102/steve
```

in greeting.php :

```
function index($order,$name)
{
    echo "order: $order , name : $name ! ";
}
```

in route.php :

```
$route['greeting/(:num)/(:any)'] = "greeting/index/$1/$2";
```

result I get :

```
order : , name : steve !
```

Comment: This should be working the way you have it set up. The fact that `name` comes through but `order` does not is strange - but implies that the route is indeed working. I suspect there's more to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it's **right** to use double quotes. It's even indicated like this in the manual (beside having done it a hundred times), so I don't see the problem @cwallenpool is pointing out.
Your routing looks fine, be sure it is called  *after* the reserved routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['greeting/(:num)/(:any)'] = "greeting/index/$1/$2";
```

.
I suggest you to try using `$this->uri->rsegment(n)` (info on [user guide here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)) to catch the rerouted uri segment that's causing you trouble. (similar to `$this->uri->segment(n)` but designed specifically for rerouted URIs)

You can also try changing the `$config['uri_protocol']` from AUTO to PATH_INFO (or one of the other alternatives) and see if the problem doesn't sit there. Remember also to delete the 'index.php' part in `$config['index_page']` if you're using htaccess to delete the index.php from you URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently written a library that can provide ease in such cases. I pass the values to the required variables via name rather numbering. Also the names are included in routes to easy reference them.

May be you can have a look at it, could be useful in your case.

https://github.com/aajiwani/LaravelRoutingForCodeIgniter